# Proper way to avoid asking for password on every pull on production server

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, repository

I cloned repository from bitbucket but with my username like

git pull username@repository.blah

now it asks me for my bitbucket password every time. Now other developers want to pull too, but what should I do to make it easy for every developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SSH (not HTTPS):

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:<your-usert>/<your-repo>.git
```

Create ssh key files using `ssh-keygen` utility (all questions you may answer `yes`). Add a public key content to User->Butbucket settings->SSH keys.

Now you can use any git command without enter your password

Comment: thank ou, that helps a lot, but it still asks me for the password for git@repository.blah

Comment: my password does not work since I'm pulling from "user git"

Comment: Your authorization to any BitBucket repository is based on your user account in BitBucket. If your user has no permission to the repository, how are you planning to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git config --global credential.helper manager`. So you need to input your username and password for the first time, then it will not ask for password next time.

Comment: yeah, but I wouldn't like to store my password for other people

Comment: Alternatively use the credential helper to just cache the password. That way it's not permanently stored, see: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/