# Pulling A Commit from BitBucket in Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket, android-studio-2.2

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.2.2. I have several commits in BitBucket, but I want to pull a specific commit into a new Android Studio project.

I understand there is a BitBucket plugin, however I do not see any way to install the plugin in Android Studio 2.2.2. I also know that there are 2 methods of cloning in Git: SSH and HTTPS. Not sure which one to use or what the best method of pulling a specific commit would be. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with Android Studio and Bitbucket plugin, but the following information may be useful for you.

SSH or HTTPS. I recommend to use SSH method, in this case you should never enter your password for connect with Bitbucket server. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40632487/637589

After you've cloned the repository you have `master` as a current branch. If you want just review all files in specific commit use this command line:

```
git checkout <your-commit-SHA1>
```

If want to work (change, commit and so on) basing on this commit - you need to create a new branch:

```
git checkout <your-commit-SHA1> -b <name-of-new-branch>
```

I believe you can do the same things using any git plugin to Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about BitBucket. It's a regular git repository. I don't think you need a plugin.

First, setup your project with git (there are many tutorials on the internet). The way I do it:

- Create new repository on BitBucket
- open command line and go to the path where you want your new project
- type git clone {git url} (you can find it in BitBucket under Overview: git@bitbucket.org:../...git)
- open this newly created folder in Android Studio

If you want to checkout a specific commit you can do it in the command line:

```
git checkout <commit-SHA1>
```

Or you can do it in Android Studio. Click on the Version Control and you'll see all the commits:

[image]

Right-click on your specific commit and select Checkout revision.

Comment: Much appreciated, can you walk me through in more detail? I am going to create a new project in Android Studio from version control first and then not sure what to do next...